# Backbone vanilla model returning undefined for 'set'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**app.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'background',
  'views/popup',
  'views/playlist',
  'models/popup',
], function($, _, Backbone, Background, PopupView, PlaylistView, PopupModel) {
  var init = function() {
    console.log("app: init")
    var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    var popupModel = PopupModel();
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

});
```

**models/popup.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
], function($, Backbone){
  console.log("inside popupModel") // this is called
  var PopupModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      alert("hey") // this is NOT called. Error occurs before this.
    }
  });
  // Return the model for the module
  return PopupModel;
});
```

Problem: When I try to create a new `PopupModel` I keep getting `undefined is not a function`, which traces to the following source code in Backbone.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options); // ERROR HERE; this.set is undefined for an unknown reason.
    //console.log(this) outputs a WINDOW object. I don't know why.
```

I am confused why I see such error with above settings. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating an instance of a Model, you should use the `new` keyword.

```
var popupModel = new PopupModel();
```

<sub>As a suggestion do not define a variable for storing the Model in your module where it's not necessary, simply `return` it:  `return Backbone.Model.extend({});`</sub>